# How to completely remove an Animation Node tree from a blender file?

Tags: animation-nodes

I do not want to keep the animation node trees in the blender file, however, even when I remove the fake user from them, save, and restart the file, the animation node trees are still there. They won't go away no matter what I've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open the node tree in the node editor.
2. While hovering over the node editor press space bar.
3. Search for **Remove Animation Node Tree**.
4. Execute the operation.

This should remove the tree completely.

I know it is a bit weird that you can't just delete the tree like others, the reason for it is a bit more technical. I don't want to go into details now.

The next version of AN will have a button in the footer/header of the node tree to remove the tree.

Comment: In nowadays version  "Remove Animation Node Tree" is gone and  now is on the upper right corner (somehow I missed it first)